# AS3 Dynamic Movie Clip name as variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

In Animate CC I can add MovieClips from the library dynamically using the following code:

```
var MovieClipName_mc:MovieClipFromLibrary = new MovieClipFromLibrary();
stage.addChild(MovieClipName_mc);
```

I want to change the MovieClip I am adding on the fly so I need to have "MovieClipFromLibrary" as a variable. However, I can't seem to get anything to work.

I hope I've explained that correctly? Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like [getDefinitionByName](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName())(...) method should work.

```
//# setup the vars
var myVar :String = "MovieClipFromLibrary";
var MovieClipName_mc :Class;

//# apply the vars and add to screen
MovieClipName_mc = getDefinitionByName( myVar ) as Class;
stage.addChild(MovieClipName_mc);
```

You could also make a function `createInstance` to take care of adding multiple vars like below:

**Implementation**:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

function createInstance(avalue:*):*
{
    var C:Class;
    
    if (avalue is Class)
    {
        C = avalue as Class;
    }
    else if (avalue is String)
    {
        // If there is actually a class in library
        // with the provided class name, then
        // C will be filled with a valid class.
        C = getDefinitionByName(aname) as Class;
    }
    
    if (C != null)
    {
        return new C;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var M:DisplayObject;

// Pass class name as String.
M = createInstance("MovieClipFromLibrary");

if (M != null)
{
    stage.addChild(M);
}

// Pass class reference as is.
M = createInstance(MovieClipFromLibrary);

if (M != null)
{
    stage.addChild(M);
}
```

Please keep in mind that you can access only the classes of the current **SWF** this way. If you want it to obtain things from loaded **SWF**s, you will need to set up some kind of library manager and get things via [Loader.contentLoaderInfo](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo).[applicationDomain](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#applicationDomain).[getDefinition](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition())(...) method.

Comment: @VC.One Why in the world did you update my answer with a block of non-working script  (your code adds a Class to the display list rather then instance)?

Answer (score 2):

That exact code didn't work for me. It gave me an implicit coercion error. However, it was super helpful because this did work...

```
    //Get Item from library
    var MCName:Class = getDefinitionByName('TEST') as Class;
    
    var MovieClip_mc:MovieClip = new MCName();
    stage.addChild(MovieClip_mc);
```

So thanks a lot!!